# How do i Empty log file on here?

Tags: server

got a error.log on server - linux 14.04 an would like to learn how to remove/empty log file

/home/xtr3amcod3s/lptv_xtr3am_cod3s/logs

Theres an Error.log there that gets filled up quick, is there a script to write or something i can do, example if it reaches 2 gigs - empty, by it self.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Best read the log and fix whatever is filling it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe one of the following

1. a cron job that `cat /dev/null > /home/xtr3amcod3s/lptv_xtr3am_cod3s/logs/Error.log`
2. turn off logging in your application
3. if you need the log, then use logrotate

Comment: I read somewhere `echo  > /pathname/filename.log` will also work.

Comment: That works too!  My thought though is that the log file is created and enabled for a reason.  With that in mind, I would ensure I configure logrotate to rotate my file when reaches 2GB, restrict the number of log files to 2 or 3, then use compress or delaycompress to save space.